# Prove the identity (complex numbers)

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

The identity:

$(|Z|^2 - 1)^2 + (2ReZ)^2 = |Z^2+1|^2$

Say $Z = x + yi$

For the left side I simplified to $((\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})^2 - 1)^2 = ... = x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 +2x^2 -2y^2 +1$

For the right side I have:

(since $Z^2 = x^2 + y^2$, therefore:)

$|Z^2+1|^2 = |x^2 + y^2 + 1|^2 =...= x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 + 2x^2 + 2y^2 +1$

Did I do everything correctly? I got $-2y^2$ for the left side, but $+2y^2$ for the right side. That means identity is incorrect?

Comment: You did it right before you edited your answer, $z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$

Comment: "That means identity is incorrect?"  It would but as it is a sign error more likely it just means you made an error somewhere.  Try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track

- $(|z|^2-1)^2+(2\mathfrak{R}(z))^2=(x^2+y^2-1)^2+(2x)^2$
- $|z^2+1|^2=|x^2-y^2+1+2xyi|^2=(x^2-y^2+1)^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2-(y^2-1))^2+(2xy)^2$

We can now compare: $$(x^2+(y^2-1))^2+(2x)^2=(x^2)^2+2(x^2)(y^2-1)+(y^2-1)^2+(2x)^2\\(x^2-(y^2-1))^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2)^2-2(x^2)(y^2-1)+(y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2$$

Comment: am I allowed to separate `2xy` because it's the `b` in `a+bi`? I just thought about that actually.

Comment: @user3132457 Yes! And this is precisely because, as you say, if $z=a+bi$ then $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

*A simpler way*:

Remember that $|z|^2=z\bar z$ and  $z+\bar z=2\operatorname{Re}z$. Now, the l.h.s. transforms as
\begin{align}
(|Z|^2 - 1)^2 + (2\operatorname{Re}Z)^2&=(z\bar z-1)^2+(z+\bar z)^2\\
&=(z^2\bar z^2-2z\bar z+1)+(z^2+2z\bar z+\bar z^2)\\
&=z^2\bar z^2+z^2+\bar z^2+1\\
&=(z^2+1)(\bar z^2+1)\quad\text{by a high-school identity.}\\
&= (z^2+1)(\overline{\smash{z^2}+1\mathstrut})
\end{align}

Comment: D'oh.  $2Re Z = z - \overline z$.  That was the bit I *knew* I was missing!  I'm sure your method is the intended way.

Comment: With a $-$,  you obtain the imaginary part

Comment: Yeah, I know.  And I knew we were supposed to avoid the training wheels or writing $z$ as $x + yi$.  But I had a serious brain fart in that I was not recognizing how to get $Re(z)$ from $z$ without the training wheels.  $Re z= \frac 12 (z + \overline z)$ and $Im z = \frac 12(z - \overline z)$ is standard usually taught in the third day or sooner.  I just .... hiccupped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it right. Note that:

- $\bigl\lvert(x+yi)^2+1\bigr\rvert^2=\bigl((x^2-y^2)+1\bigr)^2+(2xy)^2=x^4+y^4+2x^2-2y^2+2x^2y^2+1$;
- $\bigl(\lvert x+yi\rvert^2-1\bigr)^2=(x^2+y^2-1)^2=x^4+y^4-2x^2-2y^2+2x^2y^2+1$.

If you add $4x^2\bigl(=(2x)^2\bigr)$ to the second expression, you get the first one. So…

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$
|Z|^2=Z\bar{Z}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\operatorname{Re}Z=\frac{Z+\bar{Z}}{2}
$$
Therefore
\begin{gather}
(|Z|^2-1)^2=(Z\bar{Z}-1)^2=Z^2\bar{Z}^2-2Z\bar{Z}+1\\[6px]
(2\operatorname{Re}Z)^2=(Z+\bar{Z})^2=Z^2+2Z\bar{Z}+\bar{Z}^2
\end{gather}
Hence the left hand side becomes
$$
Z^2\bar{Z}^2-2Z\bar{Z}+1+Z^2+2Z\bar{Z}+\bar{Z}^2=
Z^2\bar{Z}^2+Z^2+\bar{Z}^2+1=(Z^2+1)(\bar{Z}^2+1)=|Z^2+1|
$$

Answer (score 0):

A trick to realize is that $(a - b)^2 + 4ab = (a+b)^2$

Just continue

$(|Z|^2 - 1)^2 + (2ReZ)^2 =$

$((x^2 + y^2) - 1)^2 + 4x^2 = $

$(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2(x^2 + y^2) + 1 + 4x^2 =$

$(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2) + 1 $.

And

$ |Z^2+1|^2= |(x^2 - y^2) + 2xy i + 1|^2 =$

$ (x^2 - y^2 + 1)^2 + 4x^2y^2 = $

$(x^2 - y^2)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2) + 1 +4x^2y^2 = $

$(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2) + 1$